# How to remove stop words while searching using Lucene query in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

While searching using lucene query in kibana for the keyword "METHOD FOR FABRICATING OPTICAL", I don't want "FOR" to be considered while finding matches as it is a stopword.

Q. How do i ignore stop words in this specific case in kibana ?
Q. How do i ignore all the stop words while writing a lucene query  in kibana ?

[Kibana screenshot : Seaching for "METHOD FOR FABRICATING OPTICAL"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP5Sz.png)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're searching in Kibana manually, you can always remove the stop words yourself :-)

Another way is to go to Stack Management > Advanced settings and modify the "Query string options" by adding the [`stop` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-analyzer.html) to the options, like below:

[image]